i have error on opening word document with microsoft office online server
i installed a Microsoft Office Online Server (OOS) and another IIS web server as my web server.
my link is "https://oos.domain.com/op/view.aspx?src=https://automation.domain.com/docs/iman.docx"
but when i open this URL it show me this error: "Server Error
We're sorry. An error has occurred.
We've logged the error for the server administrator."
what i have to do to open online my word file using OOS

